Changing Font Size in ggsurvfit
I am using R markdown and I am plotting a survival probability using ggsurvfit. The output plot has very small font size that I can bearly read! How can I change the font size to a bigger size
library(ggsurvfit)

ggsurvfit(SF_ALL_OBJECTS)+
  labs(
    x = "Time in Years",
    y = "Overall Survival Probability")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.025, 0), limits = c(0, 1))

I tried adding
+  theme(text=element_text(size=24,  family="sans")) 

But this did not work.
Any advice?

Try theme(axis.title=element_text(size=24,  family="sans"), axis.text = element_text(size=24,  family="sans"), legend.text = element_text(size=24,  family="sans")) 

The package's website has examples for changing the font size in the risk table (which is presume that is what you're asking about). https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/ggsurvfit/articles/gallery.html#risk-tables

Thank you, Zhiqiang Wang. Your Suggestion has worked
